# yii how to show the custom error msg with validation failed msg

Tags: php, yii

I would like to show my custom error msg with rule validation fail error msg. How can I do it?

this set msg from controller

```
$expire_date_error = '<p>Please enter the company license expire date more than notification days</p>
                    <ul>
                    <li>Expire Date is less than notificaion days on current date.</li>
                    </ul>';
                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('expire_date_error',$expire_date_error); 

        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
```

this get msg from view.

```
<?php if(Yii::app()->user->hasFlash('expire_date_error')):?>
        <div class="errorMessage">
            <?php echo Yii::app()->user->getFlash('expire_date_error'); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

I used some code from http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/21/how-to-work-with-flash-messages/

regards
=======================+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++==========================

Update question.

This is my controller

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new CompanyLicense;

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['CompanyLicense']))
        {
            $currentTime = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', time());     

            $model->attributes= $_POST['CompanyLicense'];
            $model->created = $currentTime; 
            $model->active = 1; 

            $model->expire_date= $_POST['CompanyLicense']['expire_date'];

            if($model->checkExpireDate())
            {
                $model->file_name=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'file_name');
                $folder = Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/images/';
                if($model->save())
                {
                    mkdir($folder.$model->id);
                    $model->file_name->saveAs($folder. $model->id . "/" . $model->file_name);
                    $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
                }
            }else{
                //echo 'debug';
                $expire_date_error = '<p>Please enter the company license expire date more than notification days</p>
                    <ul>
                    <li>Expire Date is less than notificaion days on current date.</li>
                    </ul>';
                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('expire_date_error',$expire_date_error); 
            }
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
public function checkExpireDate($attribute='',$params ='')
    {
        $currentTime = date('Y-m-d', time());
        $currentTime = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($currentTime . '+ ' . $this->notification_days.' days'));
        if ($currentTime > $this->expire_date) 
            return false;

        return true;
            //$this->addError($this->expire_date,'should be more ' . $this->notification_days . ' days on current date!');
    }
```

I want to show this error with other validation failed error msg.

Answer (score 0):

Please read this

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/1/how-to-customize-the-error-message-of-a-validation-rule/

or try

```
class Post extends CActiveRecord
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            array('title, content', 'required',
                  'message'=>'Please enter a value for {attribute}.'),
            // ... other rules
        );
    }
}
```

In the above, the customized error message contains a predefined placeholder {attribute}. The CRequiredValidator (whose alias is required) will replace this placeholder with the actual attribute name that fails the validation.

Comment: thx for your quick reply. but it isn't what I want. I have 2 fields, notification days and expire date. If (expire date < (currentdate + notification days)), my custom error msg will display. otherwise, not display.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the custom validation function, then:

```
 class Post extends CActiveRecord
 {
     public function rules()
     {
         return array(
             array('expire_date_error', 'check'),
         );
     }

     public function check()
     {
         if($this->a > $this->b) {
             $this->addError('expire_date_error', 'New custom error message');
             return false;
         }

         return true;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Korotovsk, thank you for your reply. I'm sorry, your isn't what I want. I updated my question with my controller. pls look at and help me. :)

Comment: All right, just set string "Expire Date is less than notificaion days on current date." to `$this->addError()` and validation for the attribute `expire_date` such as function `check()`. Finally your check method should be: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1121289/

Comment: @tharsoe, Controller: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1121292/ 
You can get validation errors in view by $model->getErrors() and make there any layout, what you want

Comment: @Korotovsky, your "$this->addError()" and "$model->getErrors()" are good. but you know, there are nothing show another validate errors. I want to show the validate errors and checkExpireDate error at once.

Comment: Shi~, man, check this http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#errorSummary-detail This is that you need 100% :)

Comment: Have you checked that the control is going into else condition